# Karate API - How to parameterize below Json post request

Tags: karate

how to parameterize the item block in code :-

```
Scenario Outline: parameterization


* text query =
"""
{
    "add":"Product",
    "item":[
        {"pn":"12345","qn":1,"m":"mk"} 
      ]

}
"""
    Given url baseURL
    And request { query: '#(query)' }
    And header Accept = 'application/json'
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
      | item_num  |
      | 12345 |
      | 67890 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scenario Outline:
* def json = { add: 'Product', item: [{ pn: '<itemNum>', qn: 1, m: 'mk'}]}
* print json

Examples:
  | itemNum  |
  | 12345 |
  | 67890 |
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful reply, but when I inserted above solution is the my code, I am getting an error. It is failing at method post   com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate - Karate version: 0.8.008:48:19.261 ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: null
Feature: DataTable

  Scenario Outline: Test
    * def json = { add: 'Product', item: [{ pn: '<itemNum>', qn: 1, m: 'mk'}]}
    * print json
    Given url 'http://localhost/add'
    And request json
    When method post
    Then status 200

    Examples:
      | itemNum  |
      | 12345    |
      | 67890  |

Comment: @Sam - the time has come for me to request you to follow these instructions. all the best: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: it did work after converting json to string and passing string as request body. I am not sure it is correct or not.

here is updated code : 

Scenario Outline:
* def json = { add: 'Product', item: [{ pn: '<itemNum>', qn: 1, m: 'mk'}]}
* print json
* def reqBody = json
Given url 'localhost/add'; 
And request reqBody
 When method post 
Then status 200 
Examples: | itemNum | | 12345 | | 67890 |
Examples:
  | itemNum  |
  | 12345 |
  | 67890 |

Comment: @sam I am not sure either

Comment: Would it be a good practice to keep the data in a json file and then we can read that data?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan yes. please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files and https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline